# APK file runs properly when installed manually but does not open when installed from google play store

Tags: java, android

I uploaded the apk on play store. The playstore version works on most of the devices I tested except on 8.1 and 9 versions. On these two version the app installs from the playstore but fails to open(shows white background splash and crashes) when the app icon is clicked on the phone.On installing manually same file(that was uploaded to playstore) to those devices, it works perfectly.

app link : https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.samriddhi.gyan

I tried with app cache clear method,re installation

Comment: Show us what the logcat says.

Comment: https://docs.google.com/document/d/1QUAmB5QtzTwjAkn4Q7P3af8kavdLVSy8hhB59Pu3flY/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: emulator verison 8.1 and 9 is working fine on my computer as well working well when installed from my computer to other devices.

Comment: show the crash log, not entire logcat from the device.

Comment: just downloaded and opened your app on Android Oreo(Samsung S8+) and it worked fine.

Comment: @Faisal it works fine in version 8.0 but not in 8.1 and 9 versions.

Comment: @VladyslavMatviienko there wont come any crash log in emulator as well as in device we debug. App works very fine. Only the downloaded app  from playstore crashes on version 8.1 and 9. manually installed app works fine.

Comment: @Luv mine is android version 9.

Comment: @Fisal i literally have no idea why the problem is going on with prior 9 and 8.1 users.

Comment: include Firebase Crashlytics in your project to see all crash reports for your app. 
https://firebase.google.com/docs/crashlytics

Comment: I didn't get you to be honest. What version it's not working on????????

Comment: @Faisal  for versions 8.1 and 9, maximum number of users are complaining about not opening the app.

Comment: then get the crash logs from `downloaded app from playstore crashes on version 8.1 and 9`. There are a lot of ways to get crash logs from it. For example, google play's crash reporting.

Answer (score 0):

Check if your Native Library **libhobbes_jni.so** supports all platforms. I am not sure but it seems like issue is related to library support.

***From Your Logs.***

```
nativeLibraryDirectories=[/system/app/PrebuiltBugle/lib/x86, /system/app/PrebuiltBugle/PrebuiltBugle.apk!/lib/x86, /system/lib, /system/lib]]] couldn't find "libhobbes_jni.so"
```

If so, try to remove the library and check the APK.